# SVG Animation not working on several browsers

Tags: animation, browser, svg

I recently created an animation with few images and now the full animation only shows in Firefox. In all other browsers (IE, Google Chrome, Safari), the parts of the animation are missing, basically I used movement and opacity attributes. Is there any way to solve these problems. Thanks.

EDIT:

I can't post the full code, but here's some of it. Hope this will help

```
<animateTransform
            attributeName="opacity"
            begin="3s"
            dur="3s"
            type="CSS"
            from="100"
            to="0"
            repeatCount="1" 
        />

 <animateTransform
            attributeName="transform"
            begin="0s"
            dur="3s"
            type="translate"
            from="0 -330"
            to="0 0"
            repeatCount="1" 
        />
```

Comment: How about linking us to the problem? I can't see anyone helping you if they don't see the problematic code.

Comment: @Blender: I've added some codes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<animateTransform>` is for animating transforms only, doesn't work with opacity. Just replace that one with `<animate>` instead and it should be fine. And remove type="CSS" while you're at it.

Comment: Thank you very much, and that was the problem.